# notification body multiline

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

[image]

how to make this in two line like

**ALERT**

**Pending follow-ups: 9**

**Enquery not attended once: 11**

I am passing a string value **"Pending follow-ups: " + all_follow_ups + "\n" + "Enquery not attended once: " + noOfEnquiry** but not showing in two line.

I am using it **android:minSdkVersion="7"**

Answer (score 4):

Add this in your code :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message).build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Also Check this : [Notification expand](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using it API level 7

Comment: Android 4.1 supports expandable notifications. In addition to normal notification view it is possible to define a big view which gets shown when notification is expanded. There are three styles to be used with the big view: big picture style, big text style, Inbox style.

Comment: I don't think there is feature for api7.

Comment: For API 16 (currently 95% of devices) you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html instead of NotificationCompat.

Comment: @Siddharth_Vyas what is the use of setTicker(appname) and setWhen(0) here??

Answer (score 1):

You could use RemoteViews for that.

In your `custom_notification.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_notification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notifiation_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/notification_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notification_image"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notification_image"
     />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_title"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_text_second_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notification_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_text"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In notification building code:

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),    R.layout.custom_notification);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image,      R.drawable.notification_image);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, "My custom    notification title");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text, "My custom notification text");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_text_second_line, "My custom notification text second line");
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
Notification notification = builder
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContent(contentView).build();
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```